# Building an installer project in VS2017 causes "Configuring VS2013" message"

Tags: setup-project, visual-studio-2017

Just recently uninstalled VS2017 RC and installed VS2017 RTM.

We have a Windows Service solution which includes a Setup project.

When I build this in Visual Studio 2017, somehow it's triggering something in the installer for Visual Studio 2013 (which we're still using), as I get this popup appearing:

[image: VS2013 popup]

It's fairly reproducible, but I have no idea where to start with this one.

Any ideas how to stop it happening?

It didn't happen before with the release candidate.

---

**EDIT**:

So, several VS2017 updates later, this problem had got a lot worse, as it was stopping me building the setup project completely.  Previously I was able to click cancel as in my first screenshot, but at VS2017 v15.3.3, it wouldn't cancel, and if I let it run, it hung at:

[image]

So this forced my hand somewhat.  I've accepted @PhilDW's answer as he led me straight to the main clue, but I'll also add an answer of my own with more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a repair of Visual Studio 2013 because Windows thinks the install is broken (registry entries or files not as in the original VS 2013 install). If you look in the Windows Event log, Application, there should be some MsiInstaller log entries that tell you the product (by ProductCode guid) and the broken component (by component guid and file or registry name). This might help identify what's going on, but not necessarily have a clue to a fix. If it's a setup project it might be a conflict with mergemodule Dlls or prerequisites, some of which come from the current SDK.

You don't say if you're letting the repair complete, in the case that it's just an isolated occurrence.

Answer (score 3):

As in PhilDW's answer, I checked the event log, and found this:

> Detection of product '{9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}', feature
>   'Visual_Studio_Professional_x86_enu', component
>   '{E3FF99AA-78B9-4A06-8A74-869E9F65E1FE}' failed.  The resource
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\URTInstallPath_GAC\' does not
>   exist.

A little Googling, and I found [this MSDN blog entry](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2015/04/20/visual-studio-2013-continuously-repairs-producing-many-small-log-files/):

> Workaround
>
> We are consistently seeing this issue caused by a missing directory,
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\URTInstall_GAC (or
>   %SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\URTInstall_GAC).
>
> To work around this issue,
>
> ```
> Open an elevated command prompt.
> Type: mkdir %SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\URTInstall_GAC
> ```

Note that the folder name isn't the same as in my case.  I didn't notice this initially, and creating the folder didn't cure the problem.

However when I created the actuall folder referenced by the event log message, the problem went away, and I can now build my setup project without messages about VS2013.